# How to import data to a database in python 3.4 from a csv file using sqlite3

Tags: csv, python-3.x, sqlite

I am currently writing a program for my A-level computing course work. I am trying to import data from a csv file into a database using sqlight3 in Python 3.4. I have tried a few examples but i cant seem to get any of them to work. I have little knowledge of python so help would be appreciated.

```
import sqlite3
new_db = sqlite3.connect(':memory:')
c=new_db.cursor()
import csv


c.execute('''CREATE TABLE data
(settlement_id,
settlement_start_date,
settlement_end_date,
deposit_date,
total_amount,
currency,
transaction_type,
order_id,
merchant_order_id,
adjustment_id,
shipment_id,
marketplace_name,
amount_type,
amount_description,
amount,
fulfillment_id,
posted_date,
posted_date_time,
order_item_code,
merchant_order_item_id,
merchant_adjustment_item_id,
sku,
quantity_purchased,
promotion_id)
''')


with open('testdata1.csv', newline='') as f:
reader = csv.reader(f)
for column in reader:
    settlement_id = column[0]
    settlement_start_date = column[1]
    settlement_end_date = column[2]
    deposit_date = column[3]
    total_amount = column[4]
    currency = column[5]
    transaction_type = column[6]
    order_id = column[7]
    merchant_order_id = column[8]
    adjustment_id = column[9]
    shipment_id = column[10]
    marketplace_name = column[11]
    amount_type = column[12]
    amount_description = column[13]
    amount = column[14]
    fulfillment_id = column[15]
    posted_date = column[16]
    posted_date_time = column[17]
    order_item_code = column[18]
    merchant_order_item_id = column[19]
    merchant_adjustment_item_id = column[20]
    sku = column[21]
    quantity_purchased = column[22]
    promotion_id = column[23]


    c.execute('''INSERT into data (settlement_id,settlement_start_date,settlement_end_date,deposit_date,total_amount,currency,transaction_type,order_id,merchant_order_id,adjustment_id,shipment_id,marketplace_name,amount_type,amount_description,amount,fulfillment_id,posted_date,posted_date_time,order_item_code,merchant_order_item_id,merchant_adjustment_item_id,sku,quantity_purchased,promotion_id)
              values (%s,%s,%s,%s,%s,%s,%s,%s,%s,%s,%s,%s,%s,%s,%s,%s,%s,%s,%s,%s,%s,%s,%s,%s)''',
              (settlement_id,settlement_start_date,settlement_end_date,deposit_date,total_amount,currency,transaction_type,order_id,merchant_order_id,adjustment_id,shipment_id,marketplace_name,amount_type,amount_description,amount,fulfillment_id,posted_date,posted_date_time,order_item_code,merchant_order_item_id,merchant_adjustment_item_id,sku,quantity_purchased,promotion_id))
    db.commit()



new_db.close()
```

Every time I run the code the following error message is returned:

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "G:\Computing\A2\Coursework\SQL2.py", line 66, in 
    (settlement_id,settlement_start_date,settlement_end_date,deposit_date,total_amount,currency,transaction_type,order_id,merchant_order_id,adjustment_id,shipment_id,marketplace_name,amount_type,amount_description,amount,fulfillment_id,posted_date,posted_date_time,order_item_code,merchant_order_item_id,merchant_adjustment_item_id,sku,quantity_purchased,promotion_id))
sqlite3.OperationalError: near "%": syntax error

I understand that the syntax is incorrect and I am looking for a way that will insert the data into the appropriate columns.

Comment: If this is A-Level coursework, you will probably need to state that you received help from here.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The [documentation](http://www.sqlite.org/lang_expr.html#varparam) says:

> Parameters can take several forms:
>   ?*NNN*
>   ?
>   :*AAAA*
>   @*AAAA*
>   $*AAAA*

`%s` is not one of those.

Answer (score 0):

Looks like you're missing the % operator. You have the coma instead, which results in an error.

Change to this:

```
c.execute('''INSERT into data (settlement_id,settlement_start_date,settlement_end_date,deposit_date,total_amount,currency,transaction_type,order_id,merchant_order_id,adjustment_id,shipment_id,marketplace_name,amount_type,amount_description,amount,fulfillment_id,posted_date,posted_date_time,order_item_code,merchant_order_item_id,merchant_adjustment_item_id,sku,quantity_purchased,promotion_id)
              values (%s,%s,%s,%s,%s,%s,%s,%s,%s,%s,%s,%s,%s,%s,%s,%s,%s,%s,%s,%s,%s,%s,%s,%s)''' %  (settlement_id,settlement_start_date,settlement_end_date,deposit_date,total_amount,currency,transaction_type,order_id,merchant_order_id,adjustment_id,shipment_id,marketplace_name,amount_type,amount_description,amount,fulfillment_id,posted_date,posted_date_time,order_item_code,merchant_order_item_id,merchant_adjustment_item_id,sku,quantity_purchased,promotion_id))
```

The % operator will pass the values across.

Saying that, the % operator is being slowly fazed out of Pyhton 3, and should utilise the format command instead.

In fact, your code could be much improved, like this:

```
with open('testdata1.csv', newline='') as f:
    reader = csv.reader(f)
    for column in reader:
        c.execute('INSERT into data VALUES {}'.format(column))
    new_db.commit()
```